# Is there any way to programmatically handle data fixtures with schema migrations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I'm learning Symfony2 and have just learnt about doctrine:migrations. It sounds like a great way of 'versioning' the database schema and deploying new schemas in production.

I've also been reading about data fixtures for development. Is there any way to version these in a similar fashion as the schema migrations, or should I just use GIT?

Answer (score 0):

Migrations' versions have to be kept under version control. If GIT is your SCM, then it's fine.